# In CSS, how to create automatic section numbering only when there are multiple sections?

Tags: html, css, automatic-properties

In CSS, how to create automatic section numbering only when there are multiple sections?   I learned that one can create automatica numbering in front of sections by using CSS

```
body { counter-reset: section }
h2 { counter-reset: sub-section }
h3 { counter-reset: composite }
h4 { counter-reset: detail }

h2:before{
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counter(section) " ";
}
h3:before{
    counter-increment: sub-section;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(sub-section) " ";
}
h4:before{
    counter-increment: composite;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(sub-section) "." counter(composite) " ";
}
h5:before{
    counter-increment: detail;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(sub-section) "." counter(composite) "." counter(detail) " ";
}
```

which generate something like

```
1.1 XXX
```

for HTML

```
<h3>XXX</h3>
```

and something like

```
1.1 XXX

...

1.2 XXX2
```

for HTML

```
<h3>XXX</h3>
...
<h3>XXX2</h3>
```

But I want this numbering to be generated of course only when there are multiple `<h3>` tags in the HTML.  Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: We'd need to see your HTML but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0eL67xm2/

Comment: Can not be done. Go with Js for that.

Comment: Is there some simple Js I can add to this existing CSS setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `<h3>` tags are all under the same parent you can go with `:not` and `:only-of-type` selectors:

```
h3:not(:only-of-type)::before{
    counter-increment: sub-section;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(sub-section) " ";
}
```

The `:only-of-type` will only match elements which have no other sibling of the same tag name. So it'll match only `<h3>` which are the only `<h3>` of their parent.

The `:not` negates it, making the selector to match only `<h3>` tags when its parent have more than one `<h3>` child.

It reads like "Match all H3 which are not the only H3 child of its parent".